# Get string of keys pressed over terminal

Tags: c, terminal, raspberry-pi, putty, raspberry-pi3

I'm currently writing up my own ASCII Game Engine in bare metal on the Raspberry Pi 3.

I'd like to create a keyboard interface that will work like my planned NES controller over GPIO. This way I can swap what input I'm using or have multiplayer support.

My question is, is it possible (maybe using VT100 or the like) to query from putty a string of the keys being pressed at any given time? My plan is to pull the state of any button being pressed (ie no interrupts).

How can I ask for or constantly receive the keys being pressed? I'm assuming putty wont send me the keys pressed in this scenario: A + B + Left Arrow.

Thanks :)

Comment: Since you wouldn't want to use a python lib such as RPi.GPIO, perhaps a C lib such as [wiring](https://projects.drogon.net/raspberry-pi/wiringpi/)?

Comment: I don't think you get what I'm trying to do. I'd like to get the keys being pressed by the user through a putty session or the likes. How can I query putty for the keys being pressed.